# Bookmarklet to remove elements from a list

Tags: list, bookmarklet

I need to remove elements containing a certain string from a html list.
Say for example I got to a webpage that contains this list:

- wolf
- bear
- cat
- dog
- wolfcat
- wolfdog

And I want to remove the elements containing string "cat"
So the result will be

- wolf
- bear
- dog
- wolfdog

Is it possible to do it in with bookmarklet? If not possible with a bookmarklet then maybe with some other tool (like GreaseMonkey / JavaScript)?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the permission from Wikipedia user BrandonXLF to post [his script](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Village_pump_(technical)&diff=948423993&oldid=948421976):

```
javascript:(function(){for(var a=document.getElementsByTagName("li"),b=prompt("Please enter a string to search for:"),c=0;c<a.length;c++)a[c].style.display=a[c].innerText.includes(b)?"none":""})()
```

Comment: For the logic part it takes every li element on the page checks if it includes the string you specify in the popup, the li is unhidden else it is hidden. I just realized this logic is the opposite of what the question is asking so the correct script would be `javascript:(function(){for(var a=document.getElementsByTagName("li"),b=prompt("Please enter a string to search for:"),c=0;c<a.length;c++)a[c].style.display=a[c].innerText.includes(b)?"none":""})()` to hide li elements containing the string.